# Exactly replicating the ColorToAlpha to MagickCore

Tags: imagemagick

So I have been trying to get the GIMP-like Color-To-Alpha in the MagickCore C API. But there are some issues that I have been facing with it. I tried to look at Fred's scripts
It does not really replicates the GIMP's Color To Alpha exactly, since it is calculating the differences but does not seem to do same minimizing/maximizing as GIMP

Basically, this is the formula `original_pixel = required_pixel*alpha + color_made_into_alpha*(1-alpha)`. I know the `alpha` for each pixel, I know original color, and alpha color too, so I want to know what should be the `required_pixel` to satisfy it. Basically, `required_pixel = (original_pixel - alpha_color_pixel)/alpha + alpha_color_pixel`. I need to use it in image efficiently. Using `fx` doesn't helps much I will appreciate recommendations

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214133/discussion-on-question-by-deepak-sharma-exactly-replicating-the-colortoalpha-to).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work for me with the following image, but you have to use ImageMagick 7 or compile ImageMagick 6 for HDRI.

[image]

```
magick rgb.png -alpha off \
\( -clone 0 -fill "red" -colorize 100 \) \
-compose difference -composite \
-separate -evaluate-sequence max \
alpha.png
```

[image]

```
magick  rgb.png -write mpr:img \
\( +clone -fill red -colorize 100 -write mpr:color \) \
+swap -define compose:clamp=off -compose minus -composite +write t1.png \
alpha.png +swap -compose divide -composite +write t2.png \
mpr:color -compose plus -composite +write t3.png \
alpha.png -alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite \
rgb_fred.png
```

[image]

I get the very same result in GIMP

But change the first command to what you have coded for GIMP equivalent. The second command is the one you requested. I hope that works out for you.

Comment: It seems to do the job! Thanks a bunch! What is `mpr:color` and `mpr:image` though, so I can try to make it into API

Comment: Those are in-memory saved copies of the color image and the input image, so that I can use them later. They are like named clones.